# It is normal to use "cerbot renew" every 12 hours?

Tags: docker-compose, certbot

I have read [the post about using docker with certbot](https://pentacent.medium.com/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71) and I have a question: it is normal to use "cerbot renew" every 12 hours?

I have read it on the post command about check certificate expired.

```bash
entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
```

Post command artical: "This will check if your certificate is up for renewal every 12 hours as recommended by Let’s Encrypt."

... but I can't understend - it's create new certificate every 12 hours or it is check to expire at first.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`certbot renew` will not necessarily renew any certificate. It will check certificate expiry dates, and if they are due to expire within 30 days it will actually renew them, otherwise it will do nothing. So it's safe to call it every 12 hours.

https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#renewing-certificates

Comment: Thanks for link and answer and your time :)